# hardhat, truffle, brownie, react stopped working?!? error Command failed with exit code 1

Tags: reactjs, npm, yarnpkg, truffle, hardhat

I was working with brownie and everything was working smoothly, launched my first useDapp app and it was a lot of fun. I wanted to see what truffle was about and installed it via npm and there were a bunch of warnings and it didn't seem smooth when it came to functionality so I might have installed it via yarn, expecting the package installer to fix things. It worked for a while then it started to timeout upon migration with tested code that used to launch perfectly fine? I thought it might of been a bug or some form of overlapping installation. I moved on to hardhat and installed it via NPM and it wouldn't compile, so I installed it via Yarn and it compiled fine. I went on to creating a new file and accidentally hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> when it was initializing a new file and setting the root. Somewhere in between there I tried to install the shorthand and it didn't work. It only opened a Windows help window instead of call hardhat when I typed `hh --help`. After that I couldn't call hardhat via `yarn hardhat` nor `npx hardhat` outside of the file....the file that previously wouldn't compile was still able to compile via `npx hardhat compile`?
It sometimes says "module not found", other times it says something about local installation.

I kind of got frustrated and wanted to play with react a little more and when I went to start yarn  I got an error message. I followed the prompt and it didn't work, I googled it and had no luck with their common resolutions. I tried to upgrade eslint and even install 7.11.0 and it keeps saying I have version 5.16.0?.

EDIT: not sure if it is relevant, I tried to update my yarn to 1.22.17 and it said it did, although it says im running 1.22.15.

windows 7
node = v12.13.0
npm =6.12.0

```
The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:

  "eslint": "^7.11.0"

Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it automatically.
However, a different version of eslint was detected higher up in the tree:

  C:\Users\Nancy\node_modules\eslint (version: 5.16.0)

Manually installing incompatible versions is known to cause hard-to-debug issues.

If you would prefer to ignore this check, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
That will permanently disable this message but you might encounter other issues.

To fix the dependency tree, try following the steps below in the exact order:

  1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.
  2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
  3. Remove "eslint" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the package.json file in your project folder.
  4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.

In most cases, this should be enough to fix the problem.
If this has not helped, there are a few other things you can try:

  5. If you used npm, install yarn (http://yarnpkg.com/) and repeat the above steps with it instead.
     This may help because npm has known issues with package hoisting which may get resolved in future versions.

  6. Check if C:\Users\Nancy\node_modules\eslint is outside your project directory.
     For example, you might have accidentally installed something in your home folder.

  7. Try running npm ls eslint in your project folder.
     This will tell you which other package (apart from the expected react-scripts) installed eslint.

If nothing else helps, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
That would permanently disable this preflight check in case you want to proceed anyway.

P.S. We know this message is long but please read the steps above :-) We hope you find them helpful!

error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of embarrassing, the answer was in the error message.

```
6. Check if C:\Users\Nancy\node_modules\eslint is outside your project directory.
 For example, you might have accidentally installed something in your home folder.
```

Hardhat set root in the wrong directory and I ended up with a node_module folder in a parent directory that was messing things up

Reinstalled truffle globally via `yarn add global truffle` and it ran smoothly. Evidently, truffle acts up with certain NPM versions.

Hardhat doesn't seem to support global installations yet. Its been working fine being locally installed into each separate hardhat project via `yarn add -D hardhat`

I haven't been able to get the shorthand to work without invoking yarn first, such as `yarn hh <command>`